# Gravity Change on Earth

Tags: post-apocalypse, alternate-reality, alternate-earth

Ok so hypothetical situation, the gravitic force of the Earth is changed. Let's say that the Earth still revolves around the sun, and the moon still revolves the Earth in the same way, but within our own atmosphere things start to act very strangely. Gravitic force on Earth slowly shifts until it is at a right angle to what it originally was at every position, it then remains in that permanent state. Let's also say that the change is very gently continuous, so if you were to fall along the side of the Earth you would eventually die from splatting on an outcropping, but you wouldn't get insane nausea from sudden changes in the gravitic field as you fell. (These vectors also look a lot like air currents. They're not like rings, but flow relatively freely.) Edit: Also, to avoid having people fly off into space, gravity is not actually at total right angles, it is still slightly angled back to Earth just enough to prevent this. Slight changes in gravitic forces to allow for flexible gravity paths is acceptable.

Furthermore for anyone who wants to quote the *hairy ball theorem, let's say the fact that this is impossible without any points of zero gravity is circumvented by either A) The existence of 2 giant "Dead Zones" where the law of continuous change is ignored or B) Magic. Also, in this hypothetical scenario, the ground (and Ocean) is held in place by a mystical force that keeps it from getting ripped apart by the gravity, but human's can still dig into it. The ocean is completely unaffected by the change to the point that a human in a submarine would not notice any change until they came up for air.

In this scenario, what kind of major changes could this have to society assuming that the humans manage to survive the initial change? For instance, what would their settlements look like, and how would it affect current country boarders? Also what could the affect on nature be? Would airborne creatures like birds and 
strongly grounded plants like weeds become dominant?

One of the interesting thoughts I had was that if you were able to find a continuous path of "falling" that looped back on itself, assuming you had the ability to control your fall well enough to stay on that track, you could fall indefinitely. Now what if you built a "falling city" which had massive parachutes to guide and slow its fall, as well as wind turbines in the bottom to generate electricity. What could be the possible pitfalls for such a city, and what extra additions could help deal with those. (I know even with parachutes there'd be a lot less gravitic force on the people, lets say that to counter this, people had magnetic boots, or just wore really heavy clothing.)

- The hairy ball theorem is a mathematical theorem that basically says if you had a hairy ball with infinite tiny hairs on it, you could never comb the ball in a continuous way such that every hair is lying flat along the surface.

Comment: What happens to a stone that used to sit on the ground? Will it roll across the surface indefinitely?

Comment: @Alexander Yeah, I guess it would.

Comment: And if this loose stone hits another stone that's stuck in the ground, would it break the second stone loose, or mystical force will keep the second stone in place?

Comment: Oh I see, yeah I guess it could all turn into an avalanche. I guess that question is up to interpretation then, I wasn't imagining a world of rolling stones, but that could be interesting too.

Comment: "Everything is affected by lsteral gravity but nothing is flung into space" makes no sense. Everything excluding oceans and the "ground" makes no sense either. When does a block of matter start or cease being part of the ground?

Comment: Actually, the world would not be coated in rolling stones. Assuming the existence of a closed force path, as the stones accelerate laterally, their paths would diverge upward. Any object not tied down will spiral out from the earth with constantly increasing velocity. So the earth will be surrounded by a rapidly expanding ring (not a spherical shell - the  hairy ball theorem prevents that).

Comment: You know that, with respect to a line, there is an entire plane which is orthogonal to that line?

Comment: There is also the issue with the air.  It would get pulled horizontally, making it move faster and faster until the friction superheats the air and kills all life.

Comment: @TheBlackCat Terminal velocity still exists, and air isn't going to fall unless it's a higher density than the air "beneath" it.

Comment: @L.Dutch Yes, but I don't see where you're going with that statement.

Comment: @WhatRoughBeast, See the not quite 90 degree criteria to prevent objects spiraling away.

Comment: @Renan Honestly, yes I think you're right. Although I don't know what you mean by "isteral" gravity, this situation makes no sense. The problem is, if the ground and oceans were affected by these changes in gravity then everything falls apart, so magic is necessary. With that mindset, draw the line wherever.

Comment: "How would X affect society?" is pretty universally considered to be "too broad" on Worldbuilding. Can you at least narrow this down to one specific aspect of society?

Comment: @Malcoto I mispelled lateral.

Comment: If you want earth to be infinite energy source, expect infinite temperature after some time. That said, I don't see what is actual question here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My first remark concerning this is: there already is a force that pushes us around the earth. Rotation. We don't notice it, because we (the ground, air, sea, humans) are in a state of inertia where we all move around the center of the earth at the same speed. So what you're describing is... Like a magic earth rotation where everything EXCEPT the earth is moving.

The thing that bothers me the most is your part about oceans. How? Where do you draw the line? Does every kind of water still feels regular gravity? Would a ship fall?
In any logic, the sea would get out of its bed, star flowing around the world and end up digging a permanent, giant circular stream. (That's a nice mental landscape, by the way).

Basically all animals would die, save for the ones that already live on cliffs. Lizards, most birds. Insects probably wouldn't care much, unless the change of gravity comes with violent winds. Vegetation would likely handle it better, at least the ones with deep roots. That would end with messy grows, thought, since they'd still need a strong trunk to support themselves, but the sun is no longer 'above' them, but on the side.

If the change is slow enough and predictable, I assume humans would just dig deep holes that would turn into caverns on the "side" of the earth once gravity is done shifting.

Now about your "falling cities."
Permanent freefall around the earth? Way I see it, you've basically described orbit. With a strong upward wind. Think no-gravity spaces, you'll get somewhere.

Comment: I like your idea of people building settlements in the dead zones without gravity. The problem with the oceans is that when allowed to roam free they become a serious problem. It'd be great if they could just start falling in a continuous stream, but first you need to have giant tidal waves going everywhere and that wipes out a lot of stuff.

Comment: Welcome to WorldBuilding! Please note that "This should be a comment" is a reason to delete answers, which is why you should make sure to write only answers in the answer field - and not mention that you initially thought about making it a comment, because that basically looks like an invitation to flag something as "Should be a comment". I think your answer is fine. A little tip about markdown: for a soft linebreak you need to have two spaces at the end of a line before hitting Enter once. If you have a moment please take the [tour] and visit the [help] to learn more about the site. Have fun!